# Using gdalUtils to reproject hdf file in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdalutils

I am now working with GEFED dataset, which is a global wild file dataset.You can download one from FTP: fuoco.geog.umd.edu; Login name: fire; Password: burnt; The file is stored into gfed4/monthly/

My task is to translate the hdf file into tif, which can be done by gdalUtils package. I think I could firstly translate it into tif file by using gdal_translate and then reproject it to wgs64 by using gdalwarp. The first step is good but I have problem in the second step. I have no idea the original srs, so gdalwarp failed.

Based on description of GEFED (can be found in gfed4 folder in that FTP), "Each product file contains seven data layers, each stored as a separate HDF4 Scientific Data Set (SDS). Units apply to each layer after multiplying by the specified scale factor. Each data layer has 720 rows and 1440 columns which correspond to the global 0.25◦ GFED grid. The center of the upper left grid cell is located at longitude 179.875◦W, 89.875◦N.". I think the original src can be written from this statement. But I have no idea how to do that and I wondering anyone can help me on this.

My code is:

```
library(gdalUtils)
a.path<-"G:\\CAAS_Fire\\1_GEFED\\monthly\\GFED4.0_MQ_201612_BA.hdf"
sds <- get_subdatasets(a.path)
name <- sds[1]
filename <- 'G:\\CAAS_Fire\\1_GEFED\\output\\file.tif'
gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = filename)
fileproj<-'G:\\CAAS_Fire\\1_GEFED\\output\\fileP.tif'
gdalwarp(filename,fileproj,s_srs=?????,t_srs=to.srs, overwrite = T) # I need to know s_srs.
```

Comment: According to the description [here](https://daac.ornl.gov/VEGETATION/guides/global_fire_emissions_v3.1.html) (because units are in degrees), the s_srs is probably "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs". Therefore you may not have to reproject it, but simply georeference it. Also note that `gdalwarp` can read directly from the hdf file so there is no need for the intermediate `gdal_translate` step.